# Catalog price rule remains applied on expired date ranges

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, catalog-price-rules

I create a catalog rule in my store, and I set a date range.

When this period expires, prices in the store window do not update, only when the customer places the product in the cart. Can anyone help me with this?

I made sure the cron is running every minute.

#~ My Store START

- - - - - /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/mystore/bin/magento cron:run | grep -v "Ran jobs by schedule" >> /var/www/html/mystore/var/log/magento.cron.log
- - - - - sudo /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/mystore/update/cron.php >> /var/www/html/mystore/var/log/update.cron.log
- - - - - /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/mystore/bin/magento setup:cron:run >> /var/www/html/mystore/var/log/setup.cron.log
          #~ My store END

In the table in the database, cron_schedule, all jobs are completed with status '**success**'.

Well, I can only update the store prices after running the commands:

- **bin / magento indexer: reset**
- **bin / magento indexer: reindex**
- **bin / magento cache / clean**

This store runs with *Magento v2.1*

Answer (score 0):

Check all active price rules. If there is any other price rule conflicting with your current rule than you have to disable that price rule. There is no other possibility for this type of behavior of magento.

Comment: I'm sorry for the delay in replying. I still have this problem, I did what you asked and helped me understand a little bit of the problem. I keep trying.